# Create new category then count in R

Tags: r

I’m new to r. 
Have a quick question- have the data below in r:

```
Product          Price
Beef                $5
Chicken.           $10
Panado.             $2
Disprin.            $3
```

Would like the above data to look like below:

```
Product.         Price     Count
Food.              $15         2
Medicine.           $5         2
```

Is this possible using r. Thanks for your time.

Comment: First you have to label each instance whether it is a food or medicine

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's just one way you could go about this:

```
food <- c("Beef", "Chicken") # ...and so on
meds <- c("Panado", "Disprin") # ... and so on

mydata$category <- NA
mydata$category[mydata$Product %in% food] <- "Food"
mydata$category[mydata$Product %in% meds] <- "Meds"

library(dplyr)
mydata %>% group_by(category) %>% 
  summarize(cost = sum(Price), count = n())
```